# Posting using facebook-android-sdk Feed dialog doesn't work

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am using the share button of Android to share something from my application to several other apps (Facebook, Twitter, Dropbox, Gmail etc). For Facebook sharing I have used exactly the method described here:
http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/

Everything works ok but this is not what exactly I want. By using `facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST")` you just directly post something to the user’s wall, without asking for confirmation. I want to first show a Feed dialog Box and afterwards to post it on Facebook. For that purpose, I replaced the code containing this, with the following:

```
facebook.dialog(ShareOnFacebook.this , "feed", parameters, new DialogListener() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

               @Override
               public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

               @Override
               public void onError(DialogError e) {}

               @Override
               public void onCancel() {}
          });
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. When I press the Facebook share button, it opens Facebook and after login it returns to my app without posting something and without hitting an error. Before when I pressed the Facebook button something was posted into my Facebook wall and a Toast in my app with "Message posted to your facebook wall!" was shown.

Also, I tried to replace it with the following:

```
WebDialog feedDialog = (
    new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(ShareOnFacebook.this,
        Session.getActiveSession(),
        parameters))
    .setOnCompleteListener(null)
    .build();
feedDialog.show();
```

But again nothing happened. I have read (from the official sites of Facebook SDK (for example [site1](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/))) that these are the methods for posting something on Facebook with Feed Dialog but nothing works on my. I have tried to use Facebook SDK 3.0 and the previous version of it without any results. What is the problem causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            WebDialog feedDialog = new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(context, Session.getActiveSession(), postParameter).build();
            feedDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) to setup an App_id?

Sample of Stings.xml in Resources/Values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="app_id">APP_ID</string>
</resources>
```

Sample of AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application >
  <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
</application>
```